# How least painfully import library to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-library

I found a library like this: https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil but it doesn't seem to have this `compile (library's package)` thing so I'm looking for a way that could easily add it to my project or I have to do it manually like here [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16634680#16634680) ?

Comment: "I have to do it manually like here" -- those instructions are a bit dated, but that's basically what you need to do, unless you convince the developer to publish an artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/). I haven't personally used it but seems to do exactly what you are looking for as it will compile the project and host it on their maven repo for you.

Comment: Note that the library in question is an Android library project, which generates an AAR, not a JAR. I don't know if JitPack supports AARs yet -- I'm not seeing any mention of it on their site.

Comment: @CommonsWare Their documentation states they can build android libraries. Even if the repo doesn't work with jitpack as is, it can be forked and the necessary changes applied to the build.gradle file. More info here: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/blob/master/ANDROID.md

Comment: Oh, wow! So far imports in Android Studio works :D I'm astounded! Brilliant!